# Join a List of Strings with a costum format

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a list of String defined like this

```
List<String> lstHeaders = new List<string>(new String[]{"str","str1","str2"});
```

I a want a way to join all that elemenet with an specific format to get something like this

```
<td>str</td><td>str1</td><td>str2</td>
```

but get this just in online of code , something like this

```
"<th>"+lstHeaders.functionToGetFormated()+"</th>"
```

Comment: i was thinking in a lamda expresion but i do not know how to get that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq and `String.Concat`:

```
string result = string.Concat(lstHeaders.Select(s => string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", s)));
```

Perhaps clearer with query syntax:

```
string result = string.Concat(from s in lstHeaders select string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", s));
```

Comment: Definitely without query syntax yuck!

Comment: Whilst functional, in this context, I think that this will just produce a lot of inline, hard-to-read and non-reusable code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably makes more sense to write your own extension method for this. Nothing built-in will work exactly like that (that I am aware of).

```
public static string WrapElementsWithTag(this IEnumerable<string> input, string wrapper)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in input)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<{1}>{0}</{1}>", s, wrapper);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Called like;

```
lstHeaders.WrapElementsWithTag("td");
```

Comment: @eli.rodriguez He tried to follow through with your question by providing the exact method you said you needed. +1

Comment: @eli.rodriguez; That will most likely result in a non-reusable solution, and lots of inline code. I imagine this won't be the only similar use-case.

Comment: A minor update to make this a more reusable implementation of a 'wrap list elements with tag' function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `StringBuilder` class:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
lstHeaders.ForEach(x => sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", x));
return sb.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", string.Join("</td><td>", lstHeaders));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally simple string concatenation is risky against constructing meta data like html and xml. If you are absolute sure that the text wont corrupt the meta syntax, you may surely do it with with StringBuilder or LinQ. Say, those strings were already escaped.

Otherwise, you may consider using HtmlTextWriter. And it shouldn't be hard to use HtmlTextWriter in LINQ.